# Wordpress - Limit get_pages to show 5 items

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I limit the get_pages to only show 5 items?

I thought adding `'number' => 5` to the array would limit it to 5 but it doesn't show anything. Here's my code:

```
<?php 
$pages = get_pages(array('post_type' => 'page','sort_column' => 'menu_order','sort_order' => 'ASC','child_of' => 765));

foreach($pages as $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields();
?>
        <p><?php echo $fields->start_date; ?> <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>"><?php echo substr($fields->event_title,0,24) . "..."; ?></a></p>
<?php
}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error with the `number` attribute in `get_pages()`

I got around it by using [get_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children):

```
$pages = get_children(array(
   'numberposts' =>1,
   'post_parent' => $heading_page->post_id
   ));
```

and using `post_parent` instead of `child_of`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I'm posting it anyway in case somebody will try to limit results and will run into the same issue:

I don't know if it's an error or intended functionality, but when you use get_pages with a "child_of" or when "hierarchical" is TRUE, get_pages also tries to get the grandchildren as well, which returns NULL.

If you don't need the grandchildren, replace "child_of" with "parent" and add "hierarchical" as FALSE, so your query will be like that:

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
   'sort_order' => 'ASC',
   'parent' => 765,
   'hierarchical' => FALSE
));
```

This should work.

WordPress 3.4.2

Comment: Another bug in wordpress which isn't as important as adding back end colour schemes. Thanks, this worked for me. Wordpress 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running wordpress 2.8 Since `number` was added after that version:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: I'm running the newest version of WP, that's what's got me stumped!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), `number` is indeed the correct parameter.

It was added in 2.8. Maybe you are running an older version of Wordpress?

Comment: I'm running the newest version of WP, that's what's got me stumped!

Comment: @Rob strange. What happens exactly? Is the limit not applied?

Comment: It just doesn't pick up the limit. I've literally just solved it but I can't post an answer on my own question just yet.